# Why is the diffusion capacitance greater than the depletion capacitance in a p-n junction?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In a [p-n junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction) the total capacitance is the sum of depletion capacitance and diffusion capacitance and it is mentioned that the diffusion capacitance is almost a million times greater than the depletion capacitance. Why is it so?

Is this true that in a p-n junction  diffusion capacitance dominates at all situations?

Answer (score 2):

No, the diffusion capacitance does not always dominate.  To quote Sze's "Physics of Semiconductor Devices", section 2.4.4 (in the second edition) says:

"The depletion layer capacitance considered previously accounts for most of the junction capacitance when the junction is reverse-biased.  When forward-biased, there is in addition a significant contribution to junction capacitance from the rearrangement of minority carrier density, the so-called diffusion capacitance."

Sze then goes on to quantify the diffusion capacitance. The diffusion capacitance is only applicable to forward-biased junctions with an overlayed ac signal.